# Is using isTouched or justTouched multiple times bad?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Suppose you have justTouched or isTouched method multiple times in your game screen, is that bad? Is it better to create booleans and as few input listeners as possible? or it doesn't matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reference [`justTouched`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Input.html#justTouched--) or [`isTouched`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Input.html#isTouched--) as much as you like. I'd be surprised if they reevaluated on every call during a single frame. However, even if they were reevaluated each time you called them, it's likely to be one of the least of your performance concerns.

Make your game, then worry about these little optimizations later, when you're profiling the game to improve performance.

Comment: You're right: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backend-android/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidInput.java#L619
At line 619 you can see it returns a boolean. While this boolean is calculated once every time a touch happens.